# Conditionally build group in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to build a graph using the force layout in D3. I would like to build different looking nodes depending on the data. Currently all nodes have a category and a name. So I draw an `svg:g` consisting of two `rect` and two `text` elements.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
// nodes are in the form: { group: 'string', name: 'string2' }
this.node = this.node.data(this.node, function(d) { return d.id; });

var g = this.node.enter().
    append('svg:g').
    attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate('+ d.x +','+ d.y +')'; });
g.append('svg:rect').attr('h', 20).attr('w', 100);
g.append('svg:rect').attr('y', 20).attr('h', 20).attr('w', 100);
g.append('svg:text').text(function(d) { d.group; });
g.append('svg:text').attr('y', 20).text(function(d) { d.name; });
```

If the node doesn't have a name, however, I'd like to supress the creation of the second `rect` and `text`. Logically, if it wasn't for the implicit iterator in d3 I'd be doing something like:

```
var g = this.node.enter().
    append('svg:g').
    attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate('+ d.x +','+ d.y +')'; });
g.append('svg:rect').attr('h', 20).attr('w', 100);
g.append('svg:text').text(function(d) { d.group; });


// unfortunately 'd' isn't defined out here.
// EDIT: based on comment from the answer below; the conditional should
// be for the text and the related rectangle.
if(d.name) {
  g.append('svg:rect').attr('y', 20).attr('h', 20).attr('w', 100);
  g.append('svg:text').attr('y', 20).text(function(d) { d.name; });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an `each` call on your `g` selection to decide whether or not to add the label.

```
g.each(function(d) {
    if (d.name){
       var thisGroup = d3.select(this);

       thisGroup.append("text")
                 .text(d.group);
       thisGroup.append("text")
                .attr("y", 20)
                .text(d.name);
});
```

However, be aware that this structure could get confusing if you're going to be updating the data.

If you want to be able to update neatly, I would recommend doing a nested selection:

```
var labels = g.selectAll("text")
     .data(function(d){ d.name? [d.group, d.name]:[]; });

labels.enter().append("text");
labels.exit().remove();

labels.text(function(d){return d;})
          .attr("y", function(d,i){return i*20;});
```

The data-join function tests the parent's data object, and based on it either passes an array containing the two values you want to use for the label text, or an empty array.  If it passes the empty array, then no labels are created; otherwise, each label has it's text set by the value in the array and it's vertical position set by the index.

Comment: Re-read your question: I was basing this on the second code snippet, where the two labels are dependent on the name value; but your actual question says that you want one label and the rectangle around it to depend on the name value.  I hope you can figure out how to adapt my code as necessary.  The `each` version is pretty much the same, the nested selection version gets more complicated -- you need to do two nested selections, one for the texts and one for the rectangles; for both your data-join function would be `.data(function(d){ d.name? [d.group, d.name]:[d.group];});`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This looks like it should work; I'll give it a try on Monday.  You're right about the two labels; it should be a `rect` and a `text` conditionally being built, not two `text` elements.  I'll edit to fix that.